# How can I remove the attribute error in 'builtin' module as no replace attribute found?

Tags: python, replace, unicode, user-defined-functions, attributeerror

I want to make a code to replace a particular word with another one.
Here is the code:

```
def replace_word(filename):
    reading_file = open(filename, "r",encoding="utf-8")

    new_file_content = ""
    for line in reading_file:
        stripped_line = line.strip().lower
        new_line = stripped_line.replace("ғʟᴀsʜ", "Ajeeb♡")
        new_file_content += new_line +"\n"
    reading_file.close()

    writing_file = open(filename, "w")
    writing_file.write(new_file_content)
    writing_file.close()

# Example usage
filename = "messages.html"
p = replace_word(filename).lower()
```

But when I run the code, error comes that 'replace' attribute wasn't found in the object 'bulletin_function_or_method'

`Also unicode error came for the word to be found and replaced`

The terminal statement:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\PRACTICE\replace.py", line 17, in <module>
    p = replace_word(filename).lower()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\PRACTICE\replace.py", line 7, in replace_word
    new_line = stripped_line.replace("FLASH", "Ajeeb♡")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Please suggest any solution....

Some edits in the code or a fully new code intaking classes, objects too but for the same function.

Comment: I think you mean `builtin_function_or_method`

Comment: Typo: you forgot the `()` after `.lower` to call the function.

Comment: I have already written '.lower()' after the call function ..

Comment: can you write the line again please?

Comment: `stripped_line = line.strip().lower()`

Comment: `replace_word()` doesn't return anything, so you'll get another error when you call `.lower()` at the end.

Comment: You should also learn to use context managers when opening files.